# How to put a static div on top of an absolute position div?

Tags: html, css

I am building a small web application.
I have two divs. One is absolute and the other is static.
I am trying to position my static div on top of my absolute one, so that it remains the top most item.

Very simple Code Sample:

http://jsbin.com/efuxe3/edit

How can this be done?

Edit:
I have been using z-index. It seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**`z-index` doesn't apply to `static` elements.**

According to [this page](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index):

> This property specifies the stack
>   level of a box whose position value is
>   one of `absolute`, `fixed`, or `relative`.

If you make your div `relative` instead, you can use `z-index` to determine the order.

`position: relative` positions the element relative to its default (static) position, so if you don't specify a top, bottom, left or right then there'll be no difference between `static` and `relative` other than that relative allows you to use `z-index` to move your element up the stack.

**Edit:** based on your code sample, [**here's a working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/bMpH6/).

**Edit 2:** based on Nathan D. Ryan's suggestion in the comments below, you could also apply a negative `z-index` to your absolutely-positioned div. This would move it behind everything else on the page that didn't have a lower `z-index` defined.

Comment: @vondip: can you post some code? I'd imagine there's a way around it using positioned elements.

Comment: @vondip Applying "position: relative" does not alter the position of the element unless you also specify a top, left, right, or bottom value.  If those aren't there, then "position: relative" and "position: static" are identical, **except** that you can apply a z-index to the relatively positioned element. So what's the problem with position: relative?  Thus: http://jsbin.com/efuxe3/4

Comment: I know that `z-index` doesn't apply to static elements, but couldn't you just position the absolutely positioned element over the static element and set the `z-index` of the *absolutely* positioned element to a negative value?

Comment: Just tested a negative `z-index` on an absolutely positioned element in Chrome, and it seems to work.

Comment: @Nathan D. Ryan: It's a good point, you can do that.  As static is the default though you'd be moving that element behind everything that didn't already have a position. I guess it depends on what the OP has on the rest of the page... As @Will Martin says though, `position: relative` doesn't actually change the position unless you specify it, so I don't really see why that isn't an option.

Comment: @Nathan D. Ryan: I'll +1 that if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @Town: Posted for visibility.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than placing the statically positioned element over the absolutely positioned element, you can place the absolutely positioned element behind the statically positioned element. You can do this by setting the `z-index` of the absolutely positioned element to a negative value. However, as @Town mentioned, this will also place the absolutely positioned element behind everything else in the normal flow.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a negative z-index to the other elements placing them behind the static div. This can be applied directly to the other elements or you can use

```
*:not(connectedObjects){
    z-index:-1000000000000000000000000000;
  }
```

But this does not work in internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

You could have a second absolutely positioned div to contain your statically positioned elements:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="underlay">
      I want this to appear under my static items.
   </div>

   <div class="item_container">
       <div class="item">blah</div>
       <div class="item">yada</div>
       <div class="item">foo</div>
       <div class="item">bar</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And your css is

```
.underlay {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 0;
}

.item_container {
   position:absolute;
   z-index:10;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

.item {
   position: static;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if by top you mean z-Index, you can set the style of that div with a higher z-index

```
div.divClassName {
   z-Index:100;
}
```

edit:

you can change the z-index of your div, with absolute positioning to a negative, but then you will have to do so for every other element.

Unless you really have a really good reason to using positioning to `static` you can change it
to relative, and the z-index will have an effect.io have tried it in your code sample and it works fine;

Comment: why the down vote? you had not mention this in your question, and you have not posted any code either

Comment: @Ibrahim Diallo: It's not my question mate.  The OP wants to position his `static` div above the `absolute` div, but `z-index` won't do that. [See here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index). I'm happy to remove the downvote if you update your answer.

Comment: @Ibrahim Diallo: -1 removed :)

Answer (score -8):

Work with `z-index` attribute. The `z-index` of the object which should be at front must be higher than the other ones.

Comment: As suggested elsewhere though, this would work if you edit your answer to suggest using negative `z-index` on the *lower* element.