# absolute div covers static div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent wrapper with `position:relative` and 2 child div inside, 1 child is `static` and the is `absolute`. For some reason, the `absolute` child keeps covering static one even with `z-index`. How can I force static div on top?

I want the `static` `div` content to determine the height of the parent `div` so I don't want to change its position.

The `absolute` `div` is for a background image that should appear at the bottom of parent `div`.

```css
.full-wrapper {
  width: 710px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline-sum-wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 99999;
  height: 200px;
}

.soccer-field {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 98%;
  right: 1%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-wrapper">
  <div class="timeline-sum-wrapper">
  </div>
  <div class="soccer-field">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute postitioned elements are always in front of static ones. `z-index` does not work on static elements.

Comment: `z-index` need to be minimum in `relative position` as @ssc-hrep3 on static doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5924447/3233827

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 is right. @hretic If you still want take your absolute positioned element in the back layer, you can apply `z-index: -1` to it.

Comment: @RohitVerma  `z-index: -1` would make absolut dive disappear

Comment: It's just in the back layer now, not disappeared. What exactly you want to achieve, you can share, if you have any design.

Comment: Do you not want any mouse-events on `.soccer-field`? If that's the case, you'll want to declare `pointer-events: none;` on `.soccer-field`.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError no its just for a background image which should be at the bottom of parent div ..... it doesn't have any other use , and parent div already has a bg image so i cant ad bg-image to that

Comment: You know you can combine more than one background image right? *See:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds **&** https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-backgrounds-syntax/ - it might be worth exploring this route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your `.timeline-sum-wrapper` to have a position `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

Quote from [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioned-element):

> An element is said to be positioned if its 'position' property has a
>   value other than 'static'.

Related questions on Stack Overflow:

[Why is z-index ignored with position:static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486475/why-is-z-index-ignored-with-positionstatic)

[Why is my z-index being ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814282/why-is-my-z-index-being-ignored)

Answer (score 0):

position: static is not working z-index. This have two solution

**First One:**

```
    <style>
    .full-wrapper {
        width: 710px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }

    .timeline-sum-wrapper {
        padding: 50px;
        clear: both;
        background-color: gray;
        height:200px ;
    }
    .soccer-field {
        position: absolute;
        height: 200px;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 98%;
        right: 1%;
        background-color: red;
        height:150px ;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    </style>
```

**Or**

```
<style>
.full-wrapper {
    width: 710px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.timeline-sum-wrapper {
    padding: 50px;
    clear: both;
    background-color: gray;
    height:200px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
.soccer-field {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 98%;
    right: 1%;
    background-color: red;
    height:150px ;
    z-index: 1;
}
</style>
```